# Monitoring secure traffic from a Yahoo widget

Tags: ssl, fiddler, yahoo-widgets

I'm trying to log all traffic from a Yahoo widget that uses a secure connection.  Right now I'm using Fiddler with both "Capture HTTPS CONNECTs" and "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" enabled.  Now, when I do this with a normal web page, I can see the SSL auths as well as all the web traffic.

With this Yahoo widget though, all I see are the CONNECTs.  The widget complains about an invalid certificate (expected) and I hit Yes to proceed each time.  However I never see anything more than the CONNECT body with "This is a HTTPS CONNECT Tunnel. Secure traffic flows through this connection."  amongst the cert data as well.  Eventually the widget will time out and say that it can't connect to the server and it won't be able to until I disable traffic capturing in Fiddler.  Any idea how I can go about viewing all data in both directions for this widget?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible/likely that the Yahoo platform itself rejects the interception certificate. Your first step should be to try trusting the FiddlerRoot; see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp for more info.